# Different view controllers for different screen sizes

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

On my storyboard, I have created 2 view controllers; one for iPhone 5 and iPhone 6. How can I access different view controllers for different phone sizes. Online I found something that let me switch different storyboards but I only want to change one screen. Is there any way I will be able to do this or is making a duplicate storyboard with one different screen the way to go?

Comment: Auto Layout Tutorial - google it

Comment: You should make use of Auto Layout and Size Classes. Creating the same view multiple times for different devices is really a bad idea... There are plenty of tutorials and blog posts on these topics.

Answer (score 0):

I find that size classes are so error prone that I was tempted to use that approach at some point (ended up making all my constraints totally independent of screen size and orientation but that's another, interesting but irrelevant, story).

One way you could do this is using custom segues with a naming convention.  Let's say you already have a storyboard segue that links to a view controller for iPhone5 and you want to redirect it to your iPhone6 variant.
Give that segue a name that finishes with ".iPhone5". Then create a custom segue (dragging from the red square of the source viewController to the target one) and give it the same name but with a ".iPhone6" extension.

You can implement override shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier in the calling controller and, if you're on an iPhone6, respond with false and programatically trigger (performSegueWithIdentifier) the iPhone6 segue using the identifier you received as parameter replacing ".iPhone5" with ".iPhone6".

You could centralize that code in a function or an extension to UIViewController to make it easier to implement on your various view controllers.